# jQuery ajax success callback function- calling as a parameter of another class function

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below scenario is not working. While if I replace `success: successCallback` with `success:function(data){//any code}`
then its working properly.

Please help me to solve this.

**greet.js calling this function**

```
RestDataProxy.callService(params,"POST",function(data) {},"GreetCustomerSearchHelper.errorResp");
```

**Restdataproxy.js**

```
callService: function(params,method, successCallback, errorCallback){
$.ajax({
url:"http://localhost:8091/IndividualCustomerSearch",
type: method,
context: this,
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json",
crossDomain:true,
success: successCallback,
error: errorCallback});
}
```

Comment: where is `successCallback`

Comment: passing successCallback as an argument in call services function from greet.js

Comment: that looks fine... can you add `alert(successCallback)` before teh ajax request

Comment: From greet.js  i am calling callservice method of restdataproxy.js and in this method i am passing some arguments. I want to call that SuccessCallback argument as an suceess function.

Comment: where i need to add this?

Comment: just before `$.ajax({`

Comment: successCallback parameter is coming correctly..i checked through developer tool

Comment: for testing.... can you try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yaya3a1z/2/

Comment: executed fail statement, while it is getting successCallback value as i checked through developer tool

Comment: there are two scenario -1) same as earlier and working fine 2) if in greet.js i changed as abc:function(data){//any code} 
RestDataProxy.callService(params,"POST", "GreetCustomerSearchHelper.abc",
  "GreetCustomerSearchHelper.errorResp"); then this is going in else block and displaying failed pop up

Comment: Please answer this question